# What is Artist._animated used for in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am writing my own `Animation` class for Matplotlib in order to use event-based animation and it's unclear how `Artist._animated` and associated `set_animated()` function affect rendering.

My animation should use blitting and I took existing `FuncAnimation` class as a reference for my implementation. In this class `_init_draw` and `_draw_frame` methods, among other things, set `_animated = True` for each artist in `self._drawn_artists` if blitting is enabled:

```
for a in self._drawn_artists:
    a.set_animated(self._blit)
```

What is the reason for this operation? In what cases `Artist._animated` is used, and how it affects rendering with or without blitting? I have tested my implementation and I don't see any difference in behaviour with or without `set_animated()`:

```
class DataAnimation(Animation):
    def __init__(self, fig, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DataAnimation, self).__init__(fig, event_source=event_source, *args, **kwargs)

    def new_frame_seq(self):
        return itertools.count()

    def _init_draw(self):
        self._drawn_artists = plot.init()
        for artist in self._drawn_artists:  # <- do we need this?
            artist.set_animated(self._blit)

    def _draw_frame(self, frame_data):
        self._drawn_artists = plot.updated_artists
        for artist in self._drawn_artists:  # <- do we need this?
            artist.set_animated(self._blit)
```